# Multiple SQL tables added together without a JOIN

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

```
  FirstField | SecondField | ThirdField

  FirstValue   SecondValue   ThirdValues

----------------------------------------------
 FirstField  | SecondField | ThirdField

 OtherValue1   OtherValue2   OtherValue3
```

What I need it to add those two tables together into one SQL query. They can not be joined as I don't have anything to join them on and that's not what I want. I want my new table to look like:

```
 FirstField | SecondField | ThirdField

 FirstValue   SecondValue   ThirdValues

 OtherValue1   OtherValue2   OtherValue3
```

This may be very simple but I am new to SQL and have been unable to find any help elsewhere.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT FirstField ,SecondField ,ThirdField 
FROM   Table1
UNION  ALL
SELECT FirstField ,SecondField ,ThirdField 
FROM   Table2
```

If you want to remove duplicate rows use `UNION` instead.

```
SELECT FirstField ,SecondField ,ThirdField 
  FROM Table1
 UNION
SELECT FirstField ,SecondField ,ThirdField 
  FROM Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a lok at using a [UNION/UNION ALL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

> Combines the results of two or more queries into a single result set
>   that includes all the rows that belong to all queries in the union.
>   The UNION operation is different from using joins that combine columns
>   from two tables.

So something like

```
SELECT  Field1,
        Field2,
        ...
        Fieldn
FROM    Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT  Field1,
        Field2,
        ...
        Fieldn
FROM    Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the column types and count match, use UNION ALL:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM T2
```